# glob.glob sorting - not as expected

Tags: python, sorting, glob

Im reading in some files from a directory using glob.glob, these files are named as such: `1.bmp`

The files/names continue in this naming pattern: `1.bmp, 2.bmp, 3.bmp ...` and so on

This is the code that i currently have, however whilst technically this does sort, it isnt as expected.
`files= sorted(glob.glob('../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/*.bmp'))`

This method sorts as such:

```
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/84.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/85.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/86.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/87.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/88.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/89.bmp
```

> ../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/9.bmp

```
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/90.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/91.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/92.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/93.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/94.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/95.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/96.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/97.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/98.bmp
../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/99.bmp
```

In the above code i have highlighted the problem really, it is able to sort the file names well for e.g `90-99.bmp` is completely fine however between `89.bmp` and `90.bmp` there is the file `9.bmp` this obviously shouldnt be there and should be near the start

The sort of output that im expecting is like this:

```
1.bmp
2.bmp
3.bmp
4.bmp
5.bmp
6.bmp
...
10.bmp
11.bmp
12.bmp
13.bmp
...
```

and so on until the end of the files

Is this possible to do with glob?

Comment: You could ask it sort based on the number like `sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[0]))` ? Untested!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: @hansolo thanks! that did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because files as sorted based on their names (which are strings), and they are sorted in lexicographic order. Check [[Python.Docs]: Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) for more sorting related details. 
For things to work as you'd expect, the "faulty" file ***9.bmp*** should be named to:

- ***09.bmp***: (this applies to all such files) as there are more than 10 of them
- ***009.bmp*** (another example: ***035.bmp***): if there are more than 100 files - here things are even clearer
- ***0009.bmp***: for more than 1000 files
- ...

Naming the files like that can be tricky without knowing their total number upfront.

Anyway, there is an alternative (provided that **all** of the files follow the naming pattern), by converting the file's **base name** (without extension - check [[Python.Docs]: os.path - Common pathname manipulations](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)) to an *int*, and sort based on that (by providing *key* to [[Python.Docs]: sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted)):

```py
files = sorted(glob.glob("../../Documents/ImageAnalysis.nosync/sliceImage/*.bmp"),
               key=lambda arg: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(arg))[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `glob.glob`. It returns a list unsorted or sorted according to the rules of the underlying system.

What you need to do is provide a suitable key function to `sorted`, to define the ordering you want, rather than as plain text strings. Something like (untested code):

```
def mysorter( x):
   path, fn = os.path.split( x)
   fn,ext = os.path.splitext( fn)
   if fn.isdigit():
       fnn = int(fn)
       fn = f'{fnn:08}'  # left pad with zeros
   return f'{path}/{fn}.{ext}'
```

Then

```
   results=sorted( glob.glob(...), key=mysorter )
```