# Glob is not reading files in order

Tags: python, image-processing, glob

I am doing model inferencing on images. I have a folder with images, named *image_0*, *image_1* and so on. I need to read each image, do the inference job and then save them with the same name in order to merge them together to form a bigger image. To read the images, I use the next code:

```
for image_path in sorted(glob.glob(r'/patches/images/*.png')):
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
```

After the inference, to save each image I do:

```
cv2.imwrite(f'patches/new/image_{n}.png', im_bgr)
```

The line above is in the same `for` loop as `glob`.

`n` is the number of the image, indicated by a counter in each iteration.

The problem is that `glob` is not reading the images in the correct order (even if I put `sorted` before it, as I read in other questions), so when I merge them together, instead of being like this (each number represents an image):

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

the result is not ordered:

```
1   6   8
2   9   4
5   7   3
```

[image]

So, how can I make `glob` to read the images in the correct order?

Thank you!!!

Comment: There isn't a lot to go off of here. Do you know that `glob` is the culprit, or are you just assuming that? For example, can you assert that `sorted(glob.glob(r'/patches/images/*.png'))` just by itself contains the paths in the order you expected? Are you sure it isn't actually the code that "stitches" the images together that's causing your problem?

Comment: Also, how many images are in your image folder? Are they all named according to your schema? Do some of them have leading zeros, such as `image_04.png`?

Comment: The order `glob()` reads the filenames is irrelevant because you're sorting them. The problem is most likely what @PaulM said, they are not getting sorted into the order you assume — because it's not being done correctly. Please indicate *exactly* how the files are named.

Comment: I am 100% sure is nothing related to the tiling/merging code, as it works perfectly without the inference part. Following what @PaulM. said, I added zeros before each number of the image, so instead of being image_1, now is image_01, and that seems to have solved the issue. I will dig more into it and when is solved, I'll post what worked for me. Thank you both for your feedback!!

Comment: Yup, then it was due to lexicographical ordering. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357306/glob-glob-sorting-not-as-expected).

Comment: Exactly, thanks! @PaulM.